Ray class field and its conductor
Let $\mathfrak{m}$ be an ideal of the ring of integers of a number field $K$ and $S$ is a subset of the real places, then the ray class group of
$\mathfrak{m}$ and $S$ is the quotient group
$$I^{\mathfrak{m}}/P^{\mathfrak{m}}$$
where $I^{\mathfrak{m}}$ is the group of fractional ideals co-prime to $\mathfrak{m}$, and the ray $P^{\mathfrak{m}}$ is the group of principal ideals generated by elements $\alpha$ with $\alpha\equiv1\bmod \mathfrak{m}$ that are positive at the places of $S$. Let $K^{\mathfrak{m}}$ be the ray class field of $K$ correspond to the ray class group by Class Field Theory and we have that
$$I^{\mathfrak{m}}/P^{\mathfrak{m}}\cong \mathrm{Gal}(K^{\mathfrak{m}}/K).$$
We know that if $\mathfrak{m}\mid \mathfrak{m}'$, then $K^{\mathfrak{m}}\subset K^{\mathfrak{m}'}$(Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory, page 397).
Questions: $(1)$ If $\mathfrak{m}\neq \mathfrak{m}'$, can it happen that $K^{\mathfrak{m}}=K^{\mathfrak{m}'}$ and if it can happen, could someone give me some non-trivial examples?
$(2)$ Let $\mathfrak{f}$ be the conductor of the abelian extension $K^{\mathfrak{m}}/K$, we know that $\mathfrak{f}\mid \mathfrak{m}.$ Do we have that
$$K^{\mathfrak{f}}=K^{\mathfrak{m}}~?$$
$(3)$ Is it true that for every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$,
$$\mathfrak{p}\mid\mathfrak{f}\Longleftrightarrow
\mathfrak{p}\mid\mathfrak{m}~?$$

What definition of the conductor are you working with? (Tbh there's only one that comes to mind, but make sure you understand it.)

@ZsomborKiss This question has been solved.  For example $\mathbb Q(\zeta_5)$ and $\mathbb Q(\zeta_{10})$ both have conductor $5\infty$. And the two modulo $m=5\infty$, $m'=10\infty$ give the same ray class field.

@HGF, maybe I misunderstand something but isn't your example of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{10})$ already an example for (1) and a counterexample for (3)? (Only downside could be that you might consider this a "trivial" example of course.)
